# How to backport SShSession to Ant 1.7.1

Tags: ant, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I am stuck with Ant 1.7.1 for the moment for reasons I wont get into. I'd like to be able to use the [SshSession Ant task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sshsession.html) to create SSH tunnels to some of my servers. But SshSession was introduced only in Ant 1.8.0.

I have no experience with custom Ant tasks. Would it be difficult to backport this task from 1.8.0 to 1.7.1 ? Where should I go to learn more on how to do that ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the source for the SShSession task is compatible with ant 1.7.  Get the [source for this task](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/ant/core/tags/ANT_181/src/main/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/ssh/SSHSession.java?view=markup), and compile against ant 1.7 and the jsch jar.  Then create a taskdef pointing to the class you've just created (jsch.jar will need to be in the ant lib dir or specified using the `-lib` option) and you should be good to go.

Comment: Yep, this works fine (easier than I would have expected). I did have to add 2 jars to my classpath to compile the SSHSession class : ant.jar and ant-jsch.jar.